# jekyll & liquid: Sorted navigation works on github-pages but not on localhost

Tags: jekyll, liquid, github-pages

Funny thing!

I make a sorted navigation menu with liquid and it works on my [gh-page](http://pdxiii.github.io/RDDR/) like I want it, but not on my localhost. There it just stays blank.

Here is the code:

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
{% assign sorted_pages = site.pages | sort:"name" %}
{% for p in sorted_pages %}
{% if p.id != "home" %}
  <li>
    <a href="/RDDR{{ p.url }}">
  {{ p.title }}
    </a>
  </li>
{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

I use the latest version of jekyll, but what am I doing wrong, or where is the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, stupid me!

I had to `gem install github-pages`. Now everything is fine!